# Пустые значения в базе данных

Tags: php, html

```
 </tr>
        <h3>Добавление оборудования</h3>
        <form method="post" action = "Z:\home\localhost\www\Work_Log\page\journal1\">
        <span class="label"> Название </span>
        <input style="width: 5%;" type="text" class="input" name="name_equipment" >


        <span class="label">Инвентарный </span>
        <input style="width: 10%;" type="text" class="input" name="inv_number" >

        <span class="label">Картинка </span>
        <input style="width: 15%;" class="input" name="image" >

        <span class="label">Примечание </span>
        <input style="width: 15%;" class="input" name="description" >

        <br/>
        <br /><input type = "submit" name = "add" value ="Добавить"/><br />
        <br />  
    </form>
    <?php 
            getConect();
            mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
            $name_equipment = ($_POST['name_equipment']);
            $inv_number = ($_POST['inv_number']);
            $image = ($_POST['image']);
            $description = ($_POST['description']);
            $query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO`equipment`(`name_equipment`,`inv_number`,`image`,`description`)
            VALUES ("'.$name_equipment.'","'.$inv_number.'","'.$image.'","'.$description.'")');
```

}
?>
 вот маленькая форма с функцией добавления соединение есть но бд таблицу equipment идут пустые значения при том не когда нажимаешь на кнопку а когда обновляешься

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно перед добавлением соединения проверять на пустые значения массив $_POST

исходя из вашего кода запрос INSERT происходит всегда, нужно проверять массив $_POST например;

```
if(isset($_POST['name_equipment']) && isset($_POST['name_equipment']) && $_POST['image'] && isset($_POST['description'])) 
{
    // Валидация переменных перед запросом (избежать sql инъекций) 
    // Выполняется создание подключения к бд и запрос 
}
```